# getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2 returning different values each time

Tags: web3.js

I have run the getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2() method of the Connection class of the solana/web3.js library. Sometimes I get only 1 confirmed signature, and sometimes I get 25. I have not changed anything about the call in between calls.

here is the relevant code I wrote:

var connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection("https://explorer-api.devnet.solana.com/");

var globalKey = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("2Gqjosh4saBRQwNAz7APn2UtnQXMfZa23ZyMggbbZCQD");

var sigs = await connection.getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2(globalKey, {"limit": 25});

The same thing also happens with different URLs as input into solanaWeb3.Connection()
If you need more information, please let me know and I will be happy to provide it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

The connection URL appears it may be invalid:
var connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection("https://explorer-api.devnet.solana.com/");

```
Instead use:
https://api.devnet.solana.com
```

According to docs.solana.com getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2 has been deprecated.
ref: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#deprecated-methods

```
Instead use: getSignaturesForAddress
```

Here is an example to perform your query:

```
curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
    "params": [
      "2Gqjosh4saBRQwNAz7APn2UtnQXMfZa23ZyMggbbZCQD",
      {
        "limit": 10
      }
    ]
  }
'
```